# Merge and lowercase Directories and FIles

Tags: unix, rename, filenames

I have a directory like this

```
root/A/b/SomeFile.jpg
root/A/B/OtherFIle.jpg
root/a/D/yet_again.jpg
```

And I would like this

```
root/a/b/somefile.jpg
root/a/b/otherfile.jpg
root/a/d/yet_again.jpg
```

OR

```
other_root/a/b ...
```

I'm happy with assuming that there aren't collisions.

How could I do this in a bash or python script (or something prebuilt to sort files and directories)?

I'd do by hand, but there are thousands of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory zsh solution:

```
for x in root/**/*(On); do mv -i $x ${x:h}/${x:t:l}; done
```

This will ask for confirmation in case of a collision.

Explanation: `**` means all (sub)*directories, recursively. `(On)` sorts in decreasing lexicographic order, so that directories always turn up after their contents. `${x:h}` means the directory name part of `$x`, `${x:t}` means its base name, and the `:l` converts to lowercase.

Bash 4 might be able to do it, since it has `**`, but I don't know if it has an equivalent of `(On)`.

Comment: Wow, cool one-(ish) liner.  But two (or one and a half) issues.

1) the OP wants to normalize the dir names too.  I don't know zsh but i'm assuming:
`mv -i $x ${x:h:l}/${x:t:l}`
would work.
And at this point, you may need to create the subdirs.
`[ ! -d ${x:h:l} ] && mkdir -p ${x:h:l}`

Comment: @Rich: `**/*(On)` matches directories too, so they will be downcased. And because of `(On)`, directories are downcased *after* their contents, which is why the `mv` command is careful *not* to lowercase the directory part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very specific, non-general way to solve this problem, which I'd call 'brute force' at best.

```
import os
import re
import shutil

path = os.getcwd()
newpath = os.path.join(path,'..','newpics')
for item in os.listdir(path):
    path1 = os.path.join(path,item)
    if os.path.isdir(path1):
        for item_2 in os.listdir(path1):
            path2 = os.path.join(path1,item_2)
            for item_3 in os.listdir(path2):
                path3 = os.path.join(path2,item_3)
                item_lc = item.lower()
                item_2lc = item_2.lower()
                item_3lc = item_3.lower()
                pic_path = os.path.join(newpath,item_lc,item_2lc,item_3lc)
                print os.path.join(path,item,item_2,item_3)
                print pic_path
                try:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.join(newpath,item_lc,item_2lc))
                except OSError:
                    pass
                shutil.copyfile(path3,pic_path)
```